# Notepad++ find and replace string or text with new string or text

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-editors, text-editing

I have some code several hundred lines long and I want to find each "String" and replace it with a different "String".  Example below...

$BR360Button.Add_Click({BR360Button})

$BR368Button.Add_Click({BR368Button})

$BR370Button.Add_Click({BR370Button})

I want to find, **({BR360Button})** and replace with **{(new-object -Com WScript.Network).RemoveNetworkDrive("M:"),(start-sleep 1),(new-object -Com WScript.Network).MapNetworkDrive("M:" , "\3600-co\data\store")}**

Then find, **({BR368Button})** and replace with **{(new-object -Com WScript.Network).RemoveNetworkDrive("M:"),(start-sleep 1),(new-object -Com WScript.Network).MapNetworkDrive("M:" , "\3680-co\data\store")}**

Then find, **({BR370Button})** and replace with **{(new-object -Com WScript.Network).RemoveNetworkDrive("M:"),(start-sleep 1),(new-object -Com WScript.Network).MapNetworkDrive("M:" , "\3700-co\data\store")}**

and so on through the 900 lines.  I really don't want to find/replace 900 times.

Any way to do this easily in notepad++?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already included the regex tag. So what did you try?

Comment: The code I pasted in from above is straight out of powershell.  So, any seemingly Notepad++ tags in there is just coincidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I want to find each "String" and replace it with a different "String"

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `[\(][\{]BR(.*?)Button[\}][\)]`
- Set "Replace with" to `{(new-object -Com WScript.Network).RemoveNetworkDrive("M:"),(start-sleep 1),(new-object -Com WScript.Network).MapNetworkDrive("M:" , "\\\10-co\data\store")}`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

[image]

**Before**:

```
$BR360Button.Add_Click({BR360Button})
$BR368Button.Add_Click({BR368Button})
$BR370Button.Add_Click({BR370Button})
```

**After**:

```
$BR360Button.Add_Click{new-object -Com WScript.Network.RemoveNetworkDrive"M:",start-sleep 1,new-object -Com WScript.Network.MapNetworkDrive"M:" , "\3600-codatastore"}
$BR368Button.Add_Click{new-object -Com WScript.Network.RemoveNetworkDrive"M:",start-sleep 1,new-object -Com WScript.Network.MapNetworkDrive"M:" , "\3680-codatastore"}
$BR370Button.Add_Click{new-object -Com WScript.Network.RemoveNetworkDrive"M:",start-sleep 1,new-object -Com WScript.Network.MapNetworkDrive"M:" , "\3700-codatastore"}
```

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)